# Python Package not Found when Trying to Install on Anaconda Powershell

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-lab, python-install

I am trying to install PyPDF2 on Anaconda via the Anaconda Navigator to be used with JupyterLab. I am faced with the following error:

> (base) PS C:\Users\luke.xuereb> conda install PyPDF2 Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done Solving environment:
> failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
> Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done Solving environment:
> failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
>
> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from
> current channels:
>
> - pypdf2
>
> Current channels:
>
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
>
> To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package
> you're looking for, navigate to
>
> ```
> https://anaconda.org
> ```
>
> and use the search bar at the top of the page.

I have also attempted this with a few other Python packages such as Tabula and natsorted, and both resulted in the same outcome.

I've also tried changing the environment following some research by doing the following:

```
conda create --name myenv
conda activate myenv
```

Again, this did not work. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked for me by running: `conda install -c conda-forge pypdf2` as the pypdf2 package has a package in conda forge. https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pypdf2

EDIT: Also, why didnt creating a new Environment work? If the command isnt found, you may have to add conda to your PATH envirnment variable.

Answer (score 1):

`pypdf2` is now [`pypdf`](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pypdf). In order to install it, use the following

```
conda install -c conda-forge pypdf
```

If that doesn't work

```
pip install pypdf
```

For more information on the package:

- [Official Documentation](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).
- [Official GitHub repo](https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf).

---

**Notes:**

- When using Anaconda, one needs to be aware of the environment that one is working.

  Then, in Anaconda Prompt, one needs to run the following

  ```
  conda $command -n $ENVIRONMENT_NAME $IDE/package/module
  ```

  **$command** - Command that one intends to use ([consult documentation for general commands](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pypdf))

  **$ENVIRONMENT NAME** - The name of one's environment (if one is working in the root,
  `conda $command $IDE/package/module` is enough)

  **$IDE/package/module** - The name of the IDE or package or module
- [What is the flag `-c`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html#Channel%20Customization).
- `pip` doesn't manage dependencies the same way `conda` does and can, potentially, damage one's installation.